# Change variable type

Tags: c++, class, variables

I'm new in C++ and I'm from Ruby where I can declare a variable and set what I want, for example a class

```
@variable=MyClass.new
```

Can do something like that in C++? I have two classes and a global variable declared with the first one set and I want to modify it and set it to the second class, in Ruby I can do something like

```
@variable=MyClass2.new
```

My c++ code is like this:

```
TestClass1 *scene = NULL;
*scene=TestClass1();
```

And now I try to set it to the second class like I do in Ruby:
TestClass2 *newScene=NULL

```
*newScene=TestClass2()
*scene=*newScene();
```

error: cannot convert 'TestClass1*' to 'TestClass2*' in assignment

I've search here a lot and in Google but I don't find anything, can someone help me? Thanks you so much

Comment: You should forget about Ruby when you learn C++.  C++ is more strict with types.

Comment: You may learn that there is no need for this.  You can declare many variables without reusing them.

Comment: You better get a good C++ book, and read it all, SO is not a place where you will learn all the basics.

Comment: @marcinj do you know about a real good one?

Comment: @Amapoli C++ Primer by Stanley B. Lippman, 5th edition, also google is your friend - you surely are not alone with this: http://chrismdp.com/2012/01/why-i-switched-from-ruby-back-to-c-plus-plus/

Comment: @Amapoli It's a matter of taste; I like [Koenig & Moo](http://www.amazon.com/Accelerated-C-Practical-Programming-Example/dp/020170353X)'s book. BTW, the comments above are right - don't emulate one language using another. They each have their internal logic (except for Java; just kidding).

Comment: @Thomas Matthews If he will forget about languages he knows when he learns a new langusge then the result will be that he will know neither language.:)

Comment: I'll start to search the books and read them, thanks you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly address the question, the reason you cannot do this is because (I'm inferring from your error message) that the two `class`es you've defined do not share a parent. For example:

```
class TestScene1
{
    // some code
};

class TestScene2
{
    // some code
};
```

Because they are two completely separate `class`es they are not interchangeable and, in C++, once a variable is declared it's type cannot change. That said, if the two types shared a common parent, your assignment would be possible, although the result may not be what you are functionally looking to do.

```
class SceneParent
{
    // some code
};

class TestScene1 : public SceneParent
{
    // some code
};

class TestScene2 : public SceneParent
{
    // some code
};
```

This would resolve your error, but may not meet the needs of your program. You can find out more about inheritance (and C++ as a whole) from the resources users have posted in the comments, or from [this link](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/inheritance/intro/).

To clarify, your assignment would look like this (slightly different than how you've posted it):

```
TestScene1* scene = nullptr; // new C++ standards advise using nullptr over NULL

scene = new TestScene1();

TestScene2* newScene = nullptr;

newScene = new TestScene2();

scene = newScene;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Amapoli it's probably worth noting that this is heading directly toward [**polymorphism**](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/).